# Passing the user's Credential to a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF web service with an operation like:

```
public void CreateWorkItem(string title, NetworkCredential credential)
{
    // Call a method that requires credential to work.
    // I want to use the credential of the user not the server's.
}
```

But using `NetworkCredential` as parameter is not allowed.

How can I pass the client's local credential to a web service so it could use them?

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of passing user's credential as parameter? I think you can get it with [ServiceSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which:

> Represents the security context of a remote party. On the client, represents the service identity and, **on the service, represents the client identity**.

e.g.

```
    // Write the primary identity and Windows identity. The primary identity is derived from  
    // the credentials used to authenticate the user. The Windows identity may be a null string.
    sw.WriteLine("PrimaryIdentity: {0}", ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name);
    sw.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity: {0}", ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name);
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I need to get a NetworkCredential to use in my code. But I don't know how reach it from WindowsIdentity or PrimaryIdentity.